# Loading OpenCV library on Cloud Run with Java + Linux

Tags: java, linux, opencv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have some code which uses OpenCV. I have it running successfully locally by loading the libraries in the java code: "opencv_java320.dll" (in windows) and then in a Linux VM, the application runs successfully by referencing the libopencv_java342.so file.

When I deploy the code to cloud run, I get an error of "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /./libs/libopencv_java342.so". I am not sure how to load the library properly for cloud run so that it does not lose this link. Does anyone have a solution for this?

**Error:**

> 2019-07-28 16:17:10.946 CDT2019-07-28 21:17:10.945  ERROR 1 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] :
>   Servlet.service()  for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with
>   path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library:
>   /./libs/libopencv_java342.so] with root cause

**Java Code Loading Libraries:**

```
String libName = "";
        if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
            libName = "opencv_java320.dll";
        } else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX) {
            libName = "libopencv_java342.so";
        }

        System.out.println("libname is: " + libName);
        System.out.println("system load.getabspath = " + new File("./libs/".concat(libName)).getAbsolutePath() );
        System.load(new File("./libs/".concat(libName)).getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the code and the error message to be **in the question** post as **test**, not *linked* as an *image*. Please, fix that issue with your question.

Comment: Test/debug this in a container running in Docker. You can then run a shell prompt to debug much easier.

Comment: Are you installing `libopencv` inside your container image through dockerfile?